# cython compilation - import vs cimport

Tags: python-3.x, cython

Newbie to Cython (perhaps this is a basic question). Consider two examples both taken from [this blog here](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html):

```
# code 1
import numpy as np

def num_update(u):
    u[1:-1,1:-1] = ((u[2:,1:-1]+u[:-2,1:-1])*dy2 + 
                    (u[1:-1,2:] + u[1:-1,:-2])*dx2) / (2*(dx2+dy2))
```

and

```
# code 2
cimport numpy as np

def cy_update(np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] u, double dx2, double dy2):
    cdef unsigned int i, j
    for i in xrange(1,u.shape[0]-1):
        for j in xrange(1, u.shape[1]-1):
            u[i,j] = ((u[i+1, j] + u[i-1, j]) * dy2 +
                      (u[i, j+1] + u[i, j-1]) * dx2) / (2*(dx2+dy2))
```

Suppose I compile the first file with the following `setup.py` script:

```
# setup file for code 1
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext = Extension("laplace", ["laplace.pyx"],)
setup(ext_modules=[ext], cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})
```

and the second file with the following `setup.py` script:

```
# setup file for code 2
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import numpy

ext = Extension("laplace", ["laplace.pyx"],
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()])

setup(ext_modules=[ext], cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})
```

In the 1st case, I used regular `numpy` and didn't import `numpy` in the setup file, while in the 2nd case I imported `numpy` using `cimport`, declared variables using `cdef` but then also included `numpy` in the setup file.

`Cython` compiles the first code anyway (and the first code seems to work).

What would be advantages of using `cimport` and `cdef` before compiling with Cython (via the setup file) versus not using `cimport` and `cdef` before compiling with Cython (via the setup file)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`import numpy` in Cython is the same as Python, but `cimport numpy` tells Cython to load the declare file:

[https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/**init**.pxd](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd)

where declares all the C-API functions, constants, and types, and also include the header files, such as `numpy/arrayobject.h`.

If you declare variable with `np.ndarray[...]`, Cython will know how to convert array element access into c code which is much faster then Python's `[]` operator.

You need to tell the c compiler where are the numpy header files in `setup.py`, so you call `numpy.get_include()` to get the path.

Answer (score 2):

Cython can compile normal python code, so your first one compiles.

Generally speaking, the more types you mark up for cython, the more chance you will get better performance. So it is your decision if you want to trade flexibility for speed.

Run `cython -a your_test.pyx` to see an annotated version of how cython would compile your code. The yellow means your code converts to a lot of C code (which roughly implies performance penalty), while white means it converts to only a few lines of C.

If you hadn't spent the time asking here, but instead read through the [guide](http://docs.cython.org/) in the official website, you could have got a better understanding already.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happened (don't know where would I see yellow and white annotated version). I'm using Pycharm and the terminal window withing the IDE

Comment: It will generate an html file in the same place as your source files are stored - have a look there.