# How can I use external types in Cython class?

Tags: cython

I am converting a vanilla python to cython to speed up the performance. I need to define a class `PFR` with an attribute `gas`. The type of **gas** is Solution which is a type from an external library called [cantera](https://github.com/Cantera/cantera) (written in C++ with a python interface created using Cython).

```
# distutils: language=c++
cimport cantera as ct

cdef class PFR:
    cdef public ct.Solution gas;
    def __init__(self):
        self.gas = None;

    def set_gas(self, gas):
        self.gas = gas
```

When I complie the code I get this error:

```
    Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# distutils: language=c++
cimport cantera as ct

cdef class PFR:
    cdef public ct.Solution gas;
               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\[****]\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_d7002e8c4a676e8ba0827e69fe89ba2a.pyx:5:16: 'Solution' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# distutils: language=c++
cimport cantera as ct

cdef class PFR:
    cdef public ct.Solution gas;
                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\[****]\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_d7002e8c4a676e8ba0827e69fe89ba2a.pyx:5:28: C attribute of type '<error>' cannot be accessed from Python
```

I found a trick to make the code work. I declare `gas` initially as a `object` instead of `ct.Solution`

```
# distutils: language=c++
import cantera as ct

cdef class PFR:
    cdef public object gas;
    def __init__(self):
        self.gas = None;

    def set_gas(self, gas):
        self.gas = gas;

    def set_TP(self, T, P):
        self.gas.TP = T, P
```

This works fine without any errors. I can create a `gas` object, connect it to an instance of `PFR` using the `gas` attribute and modify it using `set.TP(T,P)` method.

But, I am not sure if this approach is correct because I do not understand what is happening under the hood. Could this cause performance errors when I expand the class or create multiple instances of `PFR`?

Comment: You need to use cimport instead of import.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311207/cython-compilation-import-vs-cimport

Comment: I already did that, but it did not work. I used cimport with numpy and I know that it allows you to use numpy types

Comment: Dunno then. I suspect you're giving the final error message and the first error message is probably more informative

Comment: I edited the question. I added the complete error with "cimport cantera as ct"

Comment: It looks like `Solution` is probably a regular Python type, so I think the best you can do is declare it as `object`: https://github.com/Cantera/cantera/blob/ade1a381c74d207fa1cc2f167a5d4db1d015cbb3/interfaces/cython/cantera/composite.py#L29